# Are you supposed to stir sauerkraut while it is fermenting?

Tags: canning, fermentation

I am making sauerkraut I have the cabbage and salt in the crock. I mixed it together really well as I did this.  I know it takes several days to be ready to can. Do I stir it some more while it is fermenting?

Comment: You are not the first user here to wonder about this: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/54095/fermenting-sauerkraut-should-i-stir

Answer (score 0):

I do not stir my cabbage once it starts fermenting, but I cannot say whether it would affect the ferment if you stir it.